Problems with opa configuration for own application
I am trying to use OPA as a Policy Engine in my test application. I have a node.js application running in minikube on macOS via Docker. The problem is, that since I installed OPA with quick_start.yaml from: Opa quick_start.yaml my application is no longer reachable at the address test.com (which is at 127.0.0.1).
What I did so far:

first I installed OPA like discribed here: enter link description here
everything is running fine
then I deinstalled everything, installed my test-web-application and opa on top

Now I have this problem:
When I try to access the web server at test.com, I get this error: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination
Can anyone help?
The only things I chaneged from quick_start.yaml (and yes, I also configured the mesh) is:
    apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: ext-authz
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webserver
  action: CUSTOM
  provider:
    # The provider name must match the extension provider defined in the mesh config.
    # You can also replace this with sample-ext-authz-http to test the other external authorizer definition.
    name: opa-ext-authz-grpc
  rules:
  - {}

AND:
    kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: opa-policy
data:
  policy.rego: |
    package istio.authz

    import input.attributes.request.http as http_request
    import input.parsed_path

    default allow = true

Maybe that's another clue, maybe not, I'm not sure ... But these are the logs of the istio-gateway, all other logs look good so far:
... "GET / HTTP/2" 503 UC upstream_reset_before_response_started{connection_termination} - ...

Seems that the istio-gateway can't get access to the webserver? But it worked before OPA installation, so what do I have to do?
